# create a check box that comments in/out a CSS line

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

So what i want to do is add border radius to a div when the user checks the check box and remove it when  the check box is unchecked
here is how my code looks like:

the html:

```
<div id='box'></div>
```

Add border radius

the css:

```
#box {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color: #444;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Not really any code here. Do you have any Javascript or jQuery you've tried?

Comment: I can see a div but no checkbox either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jQuery it is very simple.

define a CSS class like this...

```
.br{
    border-radius : 5px;
    -moz-border-radius : 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 5px;
    -o-border-radius : 5px;
}
```

If your checkbox looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb"/>
```

then your JS code would look like this...

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#cb").on("click", function(){
        $("#box").toggleClass("br");
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it with out using jquery

```
<script type="application/javascript">

function myFunction()
{
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("mycheckbox");
    if(checkbox.checked)
    {
        document.getElementById("box").className = "border-radius";
    }
}

</script>
<style>
.border-radius{
    border-radius : 5px;
    -moz-border-radius : 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius : 5px;
    -o-border-radius : 5px;
}
</style>

<input type="checkbox" onchange="myFunction()" id="mycheckbox"/>
<div id="box">
</div>
```